# App.Router undefined with Ember and Require

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use Ember.js with Require.js but I've got a strange error when I want to make some routes with this code :

```
define([
   'lib/ember/load',
   "app/views/main-views",
   "app/views/nav-views",
   "app/views/body-views"
], function(em, MainViews, NavViews, BodyViews) {

    // Create a local namespace for the app
    var App = Ember.Application.create();   
    em.App = App;

    App.Router.map(function() {
        this.route("about");
    });


    // Export it from the module.
    return App;
});
```

I've got : `cannot call map of undefined`.

Maybe, it's a RequireJS configuration problem ? But I think all data is loaded correctly.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I think the problem is that you try to set a property of the Ember object which is not permitted (`em.App = App`). So this will cause the error - if you try it out with a working ember project to set a property for the Ember object you will end up with the same behavior.

I have an ember project set up with requirejs and also grunt automation with template precompilation, you should check it out on [github](https://github.com/CoderPio/ember-require-grunt-precompile).